# How to access xdebug session on host machine for unit tests that run inside docker container?

Tags: php, docker, phpunit, xdebug, hhvm

I have a php applications that run inside of a docker container using hhvm.

My IDE is phpstorm which runs on my localhost and I setup xdebug.

The elevant part of my `/etc/hhvm/php.ini` looks like:

```
; xdebug
hhvm.debug.server_error_message = true
xdebug.enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_port = 9999
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log"
```

And in for my nginx conf I had to add specify the server name to match my reverse proxy. The reverse proxy runs on my localhost and maps the container's IP, e.g `127.0.0.1:8080` to a human readable `http://my_app.local`.

The nginx conf entry looks like so:

```
cat nginx/conf.d/my_app.conf 
server {
listen 80 default_server;
server_name my_app.local;

root /var/www/my_app/web;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

include hhvm.conf;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/sandbox/error.log;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/sandbox/access.log  main;

location /status {
  return 200;
  access_log off;
}

location ~/(assets|img|html|src|docs|bower_components|dist)/ {
   try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
}
```

This gets me a working xdebug connection when I issue a request against the server.

Yet I also want a xdebug session once I run the unit and functional tests from inside the docker container with phpunit :

```
le-docker-container:/var/www/my-app# ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit-no-coverage.xml
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

```
PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=my_app.local" "XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_enable=1 remote_host=YOUR_REMOTE_IP idekey=PHPSTORM" ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit-no-coverage.xml
```

The server name has to added to phpstorm Langauge & Framework > PHP > Server config configured. And one has to make sure that the correct pathmapping is defined.

Answer (score 0):

`xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` requires `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. Try to define it explicitly:

```
le-docker-container:/var/www/my-app# REMOTE_ADDR="10.0.0.1" ./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit-no-coverage.xml
```

or change xdebug config to use `xdebug.remote_host` instead.

Comment: This did initiate a remote session, yet there was weird behavior in the sense that it didn't toggle a line and broke out of the session once the actual test started running. I found another way, but could you maybe elaborate what might be missing?